# How can I constantly live update appended innerHTML from user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, uikit

I have a function I created where I am grabbing `.innerHTML` from an elements `id` and appending said HTML over an image. My problem is that the HTML I am grabbing comes from the [uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/htmleditor.html) HTML editor. In which users can input their markdown. I need to grab the updated versions of HTML and append those to the image as the user updates their text. Constantly re-rendering the live input. I need to also have this logic update when the user changes the theme that the user can select.

Below is a copy of the code for the function that I have created, but doesn't seem to be working. Similarly, [here](https://github.com/jshuadvd/RTVS360/tree/development) is the Github Repo for anyone who wants to give it a go. You can also see a live version of the site located [here](http://3dslides.elasticbeanstalk.com/create) , but the feature that I am attempting to add is not included in the deployed version. It is only in the `development` branch in the repo listed previously. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var slidePre = document.getElementById('markDownPre').innerHTML;
var slidePreText = slidePre.split('<hr>', 1);

var slideElement = document.getElementById('markDownPre');

        // On listen reset state
        $('#slideElement').on('propertychange change click keyup input paste',  function(event) {

          var slidePreNew = slideElement;
          var slidePreTextNew = slidePre.split('<hr>', 1);

          if(slidePreText !== slidePreTextNew) {
              slidePreText === slidePreTextNew;
          }
      });

        if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Tron Blue"]) {
            $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[0] + ' />');
            $('.slide-preview').append('<div id="slidePreTextTron" class="col-md-3">' + slidePreText + '</div>');
        }
        if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Neon Lights"]) {
            $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[1] + ' />');
        }
        if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Hello Kitty"]) {
            $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
            $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[2] + ' />');
        }

        if (worldInfo === "Tron Grid") {
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Tron Blue"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[0] + ' />');
            }
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Neon Lights"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[1] + ' />');
            }
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Hello Kitty"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[2] + ' />');
            }
        }

        if (worldInfo === "Ocean Sunset") {
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Tron Blue"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<video width="308" height="173" autoplay loop> <source src=' + themeVideo[0] + '></video>');
            }
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Neon Lights"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[4] + ' />');
            }
            if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Hello Kitty"]) {
                $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
                $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[5] + ' />');
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you mix React and DOM methods like that?

Comment: @dandavis nothing prevents you from doing that, and in some cases using the DOM is unavoidable. However, I'm failing to see what purpose React is serving here.

Comment: i was under the impression that react had a virtual DOM, and when the vDOM and DOM are out of sync, bad things happen when trying to apply a patch to a modified subtree.

Comment: My apologies, This is inside of a component called `themeUpdate` which doesn't really need to be shown, because it is a huge component and this is the only pertinent code for the functionality that I am attempting to accomplish. All of that code is located in the `main.jsx` file inside the repo listed above.